# MonadError should not be use anymore?

Tags: haskell

I have a question about `MonadError`, namely instead of using `MonadError`, it is better to use [`Except`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:Except)?

Comment: Why do you think so? These are two quite distinct things and I'm inclined to believe that they could be useful in seperate circumstances.

Comment: Could you please explain the situation, when do I have to use what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MonadError` and `Except` are not mutually exclusive. They are things of different kinds.

`MonadError` is a type class (i.e. an "interface") that defines certain operations (`throwError` and `catchError`), which may be implemented by different monads. If a function has a type signature requiring `MonadError`, it means "I will work in any monad, as long as it implements `MonadError`, because I make use of the operations defined in it", for example:

```
f :: MonadError MyErrorType m => Int -> m String
```

`Except`, on the other hand, is a specific monad that has a specific underlying implementation. This specific monad happens to implement the operations from `MonadError`, which means that any function that requires `MonadError` may be used in `Except`:

```
runExcept $ f 42  -- using the definition of `f` above
```

You could also declare your function to be used specifically in `Except`, as opposed to "in anything that implements `MonadError`":

```
g :: Int -> Except MyErrorType String
```

Such function can still be used in `Except` like `f` can:

```
runExcept $ g 42
```

But it cannot be used in *other* monads that implement `MonadError`.

The practical consequence of this is that if you're writing some local, small, simple program, it's ok to write all your functions in `Except`, but if you're writing a bigger system with a lot of modules, or better yet, a reusable library, you're better off writing your functions in `MonadError`, because then your consumers will have more freedom in consuming your library. In OO world this idea is known as "[programming to interface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming)".

One possible drawback of this is that the code might (not always) come out less performant, because the compiler may not be able to do enough inlining without knowing the final types of everything. In practice, however, the performance penalty is trivial in most applications. The usual maxim applies: first measure, then optimize.